# Associating Ubercart products with site content

Tags: ubercart

I'm working on a Drupal/Ubercart e-commerce site where I'm selling access to site content.

What I would like to do is have a My purchases page where I have a list of products that the user has purchased, and then links to the landing page for that content.

I currently have the My purchases page setup as a Drupal view, where the view has a relationship for products and orders - then the field being displayed is the (products) Ordered product: Title.

However I haven't been able to figure out a way to add a custom link to each product that can be displayed on this page so the user can simply click on the product they purchased and go to the landing page for that content, which is then access controlled by role.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What field are you using for a link from the product node to the content node? A link field? Entity reference field?